# Detect PDF file in folder and also check if it is open

Tags: pdf, export

I need codes for below. As I try to find in this website, but nothing match my need. So please if anybody write some codes.

1. It should search a file in a folder and file name should be taken from cell whatever file name I type for search and if it is open it should warn me that file is open. The file will be in PDF format.
2. File shall not be duplicate if it find duplicate it shall show me warning REPLACE or NO.
3. If it is not a duplicate than save as PDF taking whatever name I write in cells and there will 2 different cells.

Comment: Please note, that Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please read the FAQ for questions you can ask here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is code writre asking

Comment: ok sorry sir...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Option Explicit
Function FileExists(FullFileName As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = Len(Dir(FullFileName)) > 0
End Function

Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Dim nResult As Long
    Dim fName As String
    Const fPath As String = "C:\Users\KYD\Desktop\"
    With ActiveSheet

  fName = .Range("A1").Value & " " & Range("J1").Value & ".pdf"
  If Not FileExists(fPath & fName) Then

MsgBox prompt:="PDF file saved." & vbNewLine & "Location <> C:\Users\KYD\Desktop\", _
Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbInformation, Title:="Thanks"
  .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
   fPath & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
   IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Else:

nResult = MsgBox(prompt:="PDF file already exit do you want to overwrite a previous file check in below given folder." _
& vbNewLine & "Location <> C:\Users\KYD\Desktop\", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbCritical, Title:="MME")
        If nResult = vbYes Then

    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
     fPath & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
     IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

            End If
            Exit Sub

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

i try to write these codes which export pdf and take name from cells and check if the file exited in folder ask user to replace or no.

i need some codes in it which can also check if the file is open taking name from cells. if it is opened show message the file is open else nothing.